# How to select the correct tool in a specific order for an agent using Langchain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatgpt-api, langchain

I think I don't understand how an **agent** chooses a tool. I have a vector database (**Chroma**) with all the embedding of my **internal knowledge** that I want that the agent looks at first in it. Then, if the answer is not in the Chroma database, it should answer the question using the information that OpenAI used to train (external knowledge). In the case that the question is a "natural conversation" I want that the agent takes a role in answering it. This is the code that I tried, but It just uses the **Knowledge External Base** tool. I want that it decides the best tool.

```
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from chroma_database import ChromaDatabase
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from parameters import EMBEDDING_MODEL, BUCKET_NAME, COLLECTION_NAME

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model=EMBEDDING_MODEL)
chroma = ChromaDatabase(embedding_function=embeddings, 
                    persist_directory='database/vectors/', 
                    bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
                    collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME)


# chat completion llm
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo',
    temperature=0.0
)
# conversational memory
conversational_memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
    memory_key='chat_history',
    k=0,
    return_messages=True
)
# retrieval qa chain
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=chroma.db.as_retriever()
)

tools = [
    Tool(
        name='Knowledge Internal Base',
        func=qa.run,
        description=(
            'use this tool when answering internal knowledge queries. Search in the internal database retriever'
        )
    ),
    Tool(
    name='Knowledge External Base',
    func=qa.run,
    description=(
        'use this tool when the answer is not retrieved in the Knowledge Internal Base tool'
        )
    ),
    Tool(
    name='Natural Conversation',
    func=qa.run,
    description=(
        'use this tool when the answer is related to a natural conversation, act as friendly person'
     )
    )
]

agent = initialize_agent(
    agent='chat-conversational-react-description',
    tools=tools,
    llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=3,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    memory=conversational_memory
)

agent.run("What Pepito said?") #Pepito conversation is stored as embedding in Chroma
agent.run("What Tom Cruise said in the movie Impossible Mission 1?") #I don't have anything about Tom Cruise in Chroma
agent.run("Hello, how are you?") #I want the answer looks like: "I'm pretty fine, how about you?"
```

What should I do to have a correct plan-execute/orchestrator agent that takes the correct tool in the right order?

Comment: IMHO you need to play more with descriptions and prompt to achieve the result. Consider "few-shot learning" ability of GPT models and try adding more examples in prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation would be helpful here; but, apparently you can provide specific instructions to the agent upon initialization...

```
agent_instructions = "Try 'Knowledge Internal Base' tool first, Use the other tools if these don't work."

agent = initialize_agent(
    agent='chat-conversational-react-description',
    tools=tools,
    llm=llm,
    agent_instructions=agent_instructions
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=3,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    memory=conversational_memory
)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. It uses others tools before

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger the agent of your choice you have to modify the prompt.
Example:
fixed_prompt = '''Assistant is a large language model trained by OpenAI.

Assistant is designed to be able to assist with a wide range of tasks, from answering simple questions to providing in-depth explanations and discussions on a wide range of topics. As a language model, Assistant is able to generate human-like text based on the input it receives, allowing it to engage in natural-sounding conversations and provide responses that are coherent and relevant to the topic at hand.

Assistant doesn't know anything about random numbers or anything related to the meaning of life and should use a tool for questions about these topics.

Assistant is constantly learning and improving, and its capabilities are constantly evolving. It is able to process and understand large amounts of text, and can use this knowledge to provide accurate and informative responses to a wide range of questions. Additionally, Assistant is able to generate its own text based on the input it receives, allowing it to engage in discussions and provide explanations and descriptions on a wide range of topics.

Overall, Assistant is a powerful system that can help with a wide range of tasks and provide valuable insights and information on a wide range of topics. Whether you need help with a specific question or just want to have a conversation about a particular topic, Assistant is here to assist.'''

conversational_agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt.messages[0].prompt.template = fixed_prompt

conversational_agent('Who is virat Kohli')